# Issues with RegEx

Tags: regex

I am trying to make an `if-then-else` statement using `RegEx`. I want to match the text if it contains `Monty` and also contains `Python`. Also the text should get matched if Monty is not present in the text.

**RegEx**

```
(?(?=Monty)(?(?=Python).*|)|^.*).*$
```

Kindly help!

Comment: @thebjorn Can please explain?

Comment: Select the text "Monty". The "?" says that Monty is optional. `\s` matches a single space. Then match the text "Python".

Comment: Please read the question again, i don't want to match "Python", I want to match the whole text based on some conditions.

Comment: To clarify: do you want to select the whole line if "Monty" is not present OR if both "Monty" and "Python" are present?

Comment: I want to select the whole line if it contains both "Monty" and "Python" AND if doesn't contains "Monty". @Excellll I have edited the question.

Comment: Just to clarify, you want to select the entire line when it doesn't contain "Monty", regardless of whether it contains "Python" or not?

Comment: In other words, you want to match all lines except those that contain Monty and not Python.

Comment: @Excellll in short, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
(^(?!.*Monty(?!.*Python.*).*).*$|^.*Python.*Monty.*$)
```

This passes my tests, but let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Shit I didn't think this way. You're the man. I didn't make it with negation. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I am not versed in lookahead regex but just tried to build the regex from what I understood from above description. Check the [link](http://www.debuggex.com/?re=%28.%2a%28Monty%29.%2a%28Python%29.%2a%29%7C%28.%2a%28Python%29.%2a%28Monty%29.%2a%29%7C%28.%2a%5B%5E%28Monty%29%5D.%2a%29&str=) to see if this is what you are trying to do.

Comment: The tool is great, though It doesn't gives the correct answer. Check this test case out "when Monty ", it matches while it shouldn't. Since I am trying to make it using `if-then-else`, please help if you can using that only. Still your help was appreciated.

Comment: @mozart Ya, the last case doesn't work as expected. Let me see if I can correct it.

Answer (score -1):

try this instead

```
((?=Monty)((?=Python).*|)|^.*).*$
```